# what is happening behind the scenes when you buy a cardano nft, from a privte website

Tags: wallet, ada, nft

I m starting to get into coding, and I did not manage to find an answer to this question.
When you buy an nft you are asked to send an X amount of ada to a wallet, and then few min after the website automatically sends you the nft.
How do I begin to learn how to do it myself?

Comment: The documentation here is a solid way to get started: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this question as there are a few ways this could be happening. So far, I've seen the following

- Cardano Smart Contract (most decentralized solution and preferred)
- Minting Machine (very centralized and code cannot be verified)
- Manually sending

Cardano smart contracts - There is an onchain portion and and off chain portion to consider but in general you can consume a utxo at a smart contract address by simply sending a transaction that meets the contracts parameters for successful validation. When you send ada, you are creating a transaction and submitting it. The smart contract verifies that you have met the requirements and the NFT gets transferred to your wallet. (This is made more seamless with a wallet connector. Connecting a wallet and signing the transaction on the site can trigger the submit and execute the smart contract)

Minting Machines - I've seen a lot of these around and I don't like them as they are not really part of of the blockchain. It's a bash script that gets executed if it detects a deposit of ada coming into an address. Some of the ada that comes in is used to build a transaction to mint the nft. Then another transaction to send the nft to the buyers address is created and sent to the original sender.

Manual - As a developer, I've gotten request to do this manually until they build out one of the other options listed above. My recommendation is to learn the cardano-cli and try some transactions on a node. Then learn haskell and plutus to build smart contracts.

Comment: Per his description, I think he means the second option (minting machine), since he sends X amount of ADA to an address, instead of consuming a script

Comment: And with smart contracts you lose a critical feature: you know exactly what NFT you are buying, so there is no randomness behind the scenes